# How can I use a variable as a module name in Perl?

Tags: perl, module

I know it is possible to use a variable as a variable name for package variables in Perl.  I would like to use the contents of a variable as a module name.  For instance:

```
package Foo;
our @names =("blah1", "blah2");
1;
```

And in another file I want to be able be able to set the contents of a scalar to "foo" and then access the names array in `Foo` through that scalar.

```
my $packageName = "Foo";
```

Essentially I want to do something along the lines of:

```
@{$packageName}::names; #This obviously doesn't work.
```

I know I can use

```
my $names = eval '$'. $packageName . "::names"
```

But only if `Foo::names` is a scalar.  Is there another way to do this without the `eval` statement?

Comment: What do you mean by "access Foo"?

Comment: Edited the question. I want to be able to access the package variable "@names" within foo

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To get at package variables in package `$package`, you can use symbolic references:

```
no strict 'refs';
my $package = 'Foo';

# grab @Foo::names
my @names = @{ $package . '::names' }
```

A better way, which avoids symbolic references, is to expose a method within `Foo` that will return the array. This works because the method invocation operator (`->`) can take a string as the invocant.

```
package Foo;

our @names = ( ... );
sub get_names { 
    return @names;
}

package main;
use strict;

my $package = 'Foo';
my @names = $package->get_names;
```

Comment: I think I like the alternative method you described, long as I can define get_names in Foo's base class (we'll call it Bar to be original) that way I can just define @names in every class which inherits from Bar.  I'm using Moose objects if that makes any difference.

Comment: @Paul, parens are not required on method calls if there are no arguments. Some people prefer to always include an empty `()` for consistency, but I generally leave them out if I can.

Comment: Gotcha. I prefer the consistency personally.

Comment: You can consistentially leave off parens, too. That's consistent. :)

Answer (score 5):

[Strict checking](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html) is preventing you from using a variable (or literal string) as part of a name, but this can be disabled locally:

```
my @values;
{
    no strict 'refs';
    @values = @{"Mypackage"}::var;
}
```

Comment: Essentially what I'm doing is globbing a directory for *.pm and then for each file I find I require $filename.  Once those modules are loaded I then need to access the @names variable defined inside each package. I don't know the package's name until runtime, all I have is a variable which will contain the name of the package.

Comment: I'm not have a problem loading packages from a variable name - I've got that part down.  Its accessing the variables within those packages.  This answer would have definitely save me a lot of googling an hour ago though :)

Comment: @mjn: oops sorry, I'm editing my answer now to make the real issue more prominent :)

Comment: When I try this solution on Perl v5.30.1, I get an error: “`Bareword found where operator expected at test15.pl line 4, near "}::var"
 (Missing operator before ::var?)
syntax error at test15.pl line 4, near "}::var"`”