# Perl include file dynamically

Tags: perl

I have a doubt in perl , 
I need to get filename in command line arguments/switches/options  and based on that i need to include/require/use that file in my script. 
So by using that getopt variable am able to get it done. However if i have used "use strict" in my script i could not get it. Please help on this

I tried as follows and its working

base.pm:

```
our $def_name = "me";
```

main.pl:

```
my $name = "mathlib.pm";
require $name;
print $def_name;
```

When i include the follwoing lines in the main.pl and base.pm,

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

I am getting error,

```
Global symbol "$def_name" requires explicit package name .
Execution of main.pl aborted due to compilation errors.
```

Comment: Did you mean for `base.pm` and `mathlib.pm` to be different?

Comment: how does `mathlib.pm` look like?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2648517/how-can-i-use-a-variable-as-a-module-name-in-perl

Comment: Sorry its not base.pm but mathlib.pm

Answer (score 1):

`$def_name` hasn't been exported from `mathlib.pm`, it's a package variable not a global. `$mathlib::def_name` will work, or you can use the `Exporter` module to export it into the namespace of any module which uses it.

Comment: Name "mathlib::def_name" used only once: possible typo at main.pl line 8.

Comment: I tried with the following, print $mathlib::def_name;  but its showing the err `Name "mathlib::def_name" used only once: possible typo at main.pl `

Comment: Does `mathlib.pm` have a `package` declaration at the top, i.e. `package mathlib;`?

Comment: thanks for the help. i tried as in the link mentioned by Himanshu. it helped. thank u